# s3 bucket policy saying invalid principal in policy but same policy is working for other bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an s3 bucket which requires public read-only access to the public.

```
         {
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity E2XXXXXXXX"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket-qa.web.io/*"
    }
]
}
```

Above policy says Error:Invalid principal in policy

I have the other bucket which I used same policy here but it was working without any issues for that bucket.

Comment: Try "CanonicalUser" instead of "AWS" in the principal.

Comment: @jarmod still same issue

Comment: The syntax looks correct. You will get that error if the origin access identity ID is incorrect. Double check the CloudFront dashboard and make sure you have an origin access identity with the ID "E2XXXXXXXX".

Comment: @justin Howard. yes, your answer is right. I mentioned CloudFront ID wrong. It should be from the origin access.

Comment: @kalyan did you resolve this error